# Advanced table filtre using js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a newcomer and I need some help with a js code.

I want to create a tabel filter like https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp .

The script works almost perfect.
On the first 3 columns the filter work perfect, what I want more is that on the last 2 columns when you search for a dimension or code I want to display only the matched value, not all of product values.

To explain the table a bit:

Is an 5 columns table, where some of the first 3 columns have rowspan attribute because is same product but with different dimensions and codes.

If I search on dimension input the value "70" the script output all the products where is found the value 70 with all dimensions, but i want to display only the value requested and hide other values that does not meet the request ( currently it displays 170 as well as 210 values, but I need to display only the 170 values.)

I put the link for the code here: https://jsfiddle.net/mitza_dragan/vg9e0fkr/3/

Part of my js code below:

```
if(inp.id === "my" + cell.className) {
                        // Daca se gaseste valoarea din input in valoare din celula,
                        // seteaza seteaza true (s-a gasit macar o valoare in tot randul)
                        if(matchedCellText.indexOf(inp.value.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
                            matched = true;
                            // Daca s-a gasit macar un match, sari peste restul celulelor
                            // din randul actual
                            break;
                        }
                    }
```

For the complet view of the app follow the link above.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow :)

Thanks for sharing a working JS fiddle. I tried working on the fiddle and came up with a solution, can you check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7n4oa0f5/) and let me know whether it works out for you as per your requirements?

I'll explain the approach followed:

First of all, as the last two columns are a little bit different, you'll have to treat them separately. So, in case the search fields of the last two columns are not empty, we will not break out of all the loops and hide the entire row, instead we will loop through until all the cells are checked and then hide the miniRow or the entire row.

We can check whether `mydimensiune` or `mycod` inputs are empty of not by the following line of code :

```
const isDimensiuneOrCodSearchInput = nonEmptySearchInputs.findIndex( (input) => {
    return (input.id == "mydimensiune" || input.id == "mycod") 
});
```

If `isDimensiuneOrCodSearchInput` is -1 then both the 4th and 5th column search fields are empty and we need not worry about showing/ hiding any `miniRow`. This is where your code is working perfectly fine for the first three columns.

If `isDimensiuneOrCodSearchInput` is not -1, then either of the 4th or 5th column search fields are not empty and we need to check whether we should show/ hide the `miniRow` based on the cell value match.

Inside the `miniRows` for loop, a new variable has been introduced called as `isHideMiniRow` which would determine whether the current `miniRow` should be hidden or not.

Inside the `cells` for loop, if the cell value doesn't match with the input value, an if block has been added

```
if( cell.className == "dimensiune" || cell.className == "cod" ) {
    isHideMiniRow = true;
}
```

This block sets the `isHideMiniRow` to true and in the `miniRow` for loop we check for this variable and hide the `miniRow` if none of the search fields match.

Also, we'll have to again show the miniRows when backspace is pressed, so the following lines of code has been added to do that :

```
const tableRows = document.querySelectorAll("tbody.table-row>tr");

tableRows.forEach(tableRow => tableRow.style.display = "table-row");
```

I've tried my best to describe the changes done to the code. Let me know if you want further clarity in the above approach.

Comment: I found one bug: if you search 17 on dimension and 6121 on code you will see that is only 2 correct rows, but it display 3( one of them withount dimensions).
And i wanted to ask you i can update css to avoid mixed heights, (photo: https://imgur.com/a/fHMmyvH)

Comment: Hi Mitza, thanks for spotting that bug, fixed that for you. Can you please check this updated fiddle and let me know whether it works?
https://jsfiddle.net/7y3x4u8r/

Also, regarding the mixed heights, can you please clarify a bit on what you want to achieve? Sorry, I wasn't able to follow.

Comment: I tested again and i notice that the bug is fixed but another one apeared.. try to find last product from the table by articol or code, 500005, and you will not find it, I am sure that there are more products that can't be found now. This is what happend to me then i decided to at least have the script working perfect for the first 3 coloums and with that catch ( hot hidding corectly the last 2 coloumns).
I think that i will use the first version of yours, is not a big of a deal if I can find all products after all.
do you think you can fix it?

Comment: I can definitely fix it. It's quite tricky though. Give me some time, I'll try ironing out those pesky little issues. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: and for the heights problem, i want if i can make the height of the filered product to auto reseize. I know CSS but I don't have in mind any solution to resize after the filter id done. I will put a image of what i want to achieve with the height after filters are applied. i tried to explain in this ps: https://imgur.com/a/8WZsotU

Comment: Please try this updated Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/7y3x4u8r/ and let me know if you face anymore issues. Sorry for posting several error prone fiddles here.

Comment: Regarding the height problem, do you want the 4th and 5th column rows to be centrally aligned in the product row? Or bottom aligned? I'll have to think of a way of doing it using CSS.

Comment: the last fiddle still doesn't find some of the products.
for the height is ok to pe placed in the middle or to have the same height as the first 3 columns.

Comment: If you could help me out with the products that you aren't able to find may be I can fix the issue. I was able to search for most of the products using the last fiddle. I haven't done any exhaustive testing though :).
Also, if you are pasting the query text in the search box(Ctrl/ Command + V) then it might not work.

Comment: I tried the product with the code 500005 directly in fiddle.